# Add data file in CSS & Undesired files

Tags: codenameone

Two questions:

1. What are the steps to add a data file to theme.res in a css activated project?  When I open the generated theme.res with the resourceEditor, I can see the data file but the code `Resources.getGlobalResources().getData("datafile")` returns null.
2. I keep having some multi-image files "SideCommand*.png" from `Resources.getGlobalResources()` that I have no idea where they are from since they do not appear in the generated theme.res loaded in resourceEditor.

It could sound like the process is broken somewhere or I do not check out the right theme.res but adding an image to the css area works just fine.  I can see it in the resource Editor and I can load it using `Resources.getGlobalResources().getData("imagefile")`.  I'm really lost here, any chance you can guide me?

Cheers.

Emmanuel

Answer (score 0):

If you define a border that can't be satisfied by the existing borders in Codename One the CSS plugin generates a 9-piece border for you by using the JavaFX HTML engine to render the CSS and grab a screenshot. That means the css for `SideCommand` uses a fancy border.

The CSS processor supports images but not data files at this time. You can add an image using this approach: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/using-css-to-import-images.html

Notice you can add additional res files for data.

Comment: Thanks, Shai.  However, I still don't get why these images need to be generated.  The css code is extremely simple:
Default {}
SideCommand {
    cn1-derive: Default;
    border: none;
}

I must be missing something.

Comment: Was it different before? If it was delete the res file and run again. The plugin tends to over cache content.

Comment: I did not really notice how it was before.  I moved the project to css and at first the theme.css was loaded with lots of styles that I then removed to start from scratch.  It's only when I decided to watch the global resource content for my data file that I realized the SideCommand*.png files where there.  I deleted the res file a few times with my testing but the pngs remain.  Any way I can remove all the cache the plugin may use?

Comment: Try deleting the res file and the build directory too

Comment: OK, Shai.  I don't know what was the cause but after deleting the build dir, the res file and blanked out the css file content, the SideCommand*.png disappeared.  I then put the css content back and yet no SideCommand*.png.  Thanks for your help.